# Name for this illogical technique?

Tags: logic, terminology

I recently noticed a pattern of interaction with someone.  This person will start talking about something, give overly elaborate explanations that wander wildly between disconnected ideas, often using pseudo-logic.  I believe the goal is to obfuscate a message that is hidden within nonsense.  The person is trying to seem as if they are being detail-oriented and very logical and smart, but really they are trying to slip in some message or question that they know will not be received well if asked outright.  If you do your best to try to follow, which can be difficult, you really don't have time to think clearly about what is being said. Between topic transitions, the hidden message is inserted, and then in a contrived way they sandwich that message with more BS on the end, and then say... "What do you think about that?".

The believe the intent is to broach a topic/plant a seed while discouraging you from questioning the hidden message.  the disturbing part is that the hidden message is usually insulting, demeaning or usually disempowering.  At first this technique was something I didn't want to believe was happening, but over time and repeat performances (pre- and post- stroke), it is now painfully obvious this is their [MO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi).

Again, the basic question is... has anyone read or heard of a term to describe this pattern of communication/interaction.  It doesn't have to be a logical fallacy.  In fact it sounds more like a propaganda technique.

Comment: [Gish gallop?](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Gish_Gallop)

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is a philosophy question. Your question indicates a technique of "filibuster-rudeness" which is of content, not logical form. I think the general term for this is ***jerk***?

Comment: when I look at the FAQ I see it fitting in with "applied philosophy — specifically logic and argumentation".  One might argue against that, but it's the closest match I can find anywhere on StackExchange.    I feel this technique is jerkish, but we all have to deal with jerks of some kind.  I am not looking for advice on how to handle it, but just the name of what this kind of strategy is called.

Comment: I would be tempted to accept gish gallop as an answer.  As I read the beginning of your link @Raskolnikov it sounds almost identical.

Comment: I really like the term filibuster-rudeness... that's a good descriptor.

Comment: @Raskolnikov it sounds almost identical.  As a matter of fact the description of "the "galloper" as an expert in a broad range of subjects and the opponent as an incompetent bumbler who didn't do their homework before the debate" describes quite well why I used the word demeaning.  It's like a condescending "You are so small and know so little" type of stance but disguised in the middle of another less threatening conversation.  If it weren't for the diversional nature of the rest of the conversation, I would say that would be it.

Comment: So as I read, it seems like a Chewbacca with something in the middle.

Comment: It's still perhaps a little difficult to see exactly what you're looking for someone to explain to you here, but since you have put in some effort to improve the question I am voting to re-open at this time. I would still encourage you to try to develop this a bit more, maybe to specify the properly philosophical concern here a bit further -- and if you can tell us a little bit about your context and motivations that might help too. (What degree of familiarity might you have with academic philosophy? What might be you be reading or studying that makes this concern urgent or important for you?)

Comment: If you would like context, I have a relative that has been doing this to me since I was a teenager.  That's where the importance comes in for me.  Before I confront this person, I want to understand what he's been doing better.  He is a self-professed "student of philosophy" and I get the impression he feels his knowledge has allowed him to manipulate others, including myself (sigh) at times.  I guess a part of me wants to look at what other games he may have been playing.  Obviously understanding what has been done is second to how I handle confronting him respectfully.  First things first.

Comment: Gish Gallop seems the closest thing I have seen so far.  As I hinted in the first version of the question @JosephWeissman, I have zero formal training in this area.  Just someone interested in learning more to help myself understand his influences a bit better and deal with him using terminology he is familiar with, when that time comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make my comment an answer, I suggest that the technique described by the OP is in fact what is sometimes referred to as the [Gish gallop](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Gish_Gallop):

> The Gish Gallop is an informal name for a debating technique that involves drowning the opponent in such a torrent of half-truths, lies, and straw-man arguments that the opponent cannot possibly answer every falsehood that has been raised. Usually this results in many involuntary twitches in frustration as the opponent struggles just to decide where to start. It is named after creationism activist and professional debater Duane Gish.

Everything is in there, except for the introduction of a hidden message. That last part could be considered obscurantism, but this is a very broad term. Maybe closer when it comes to the hidden message would be [JAQing off](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/JAQing_off).

I must add that both terms are very informal and not standard accepted terms in philosophy, but rather in internet debates.

Answer (score 3):

A term I've heard to describe such techniques (if they are implemented with full knowledge as to their messy, illogical, deceptive nature) is [Obscurantism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obscurantism).

I have also heard people call it Post-modernism.

That was a joke.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to [straw man fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man), except your person is misleading your while asking for your approval instead of attacking your position.

Comment: "Presenting someone who defends a position poorly as the defender, then refuting that person's arguments — thus giving the appearance that every upholder of that position (and thus the position itself) has been defeated" sounds oddly familiar.  Interesting.